# Dropdown widget Python

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, widget

Please bear with me. First post for me here.
I am using Python, first programming language for me, for about two weeks. Now I am stuck..

I want to create a single graph with a dropdown widget. 
On the x-axis I want the selected year and on the y-axis I want the respective number for that year.
So the year 2009 on the x-axis and 130 on the y-axis and so on.

I tried different things, basically playing around for three hours..

Maybe someone can provide me a solution?
Thanks!

```
%matplotlib inline

import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['2009', '2010', '2011', "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018","2019"],
    value='2009',
    description='Jahr:',
    )

def Dropdown_Menu(b):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.dpi = 500

    x = [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
    y = [130, 137, 104, 147, 401, 274, 234, 770, 857, 746, 704]

    ax.plot(x, y, label = "Flugstunden pro Jahr", marker = ".")


    ax.legend()

    ax.set_title("Flugstunden")
    ax.set_xlabel("Jahr")
    ax.set_ylabel("Flugstunden")
    ax.set_facecolor((0.9,0.9,0.9))



plt.show()

dropdown.observe(Dropdown_Menu, names="value")    
display(dropdown)
```

Comment: what do you use jupyter to run it ?

Comment: i didn't run it but in `Dropdown_Menu` you always use the same values in `x`, `y` so it will always draw the same plot. You have to filter values to get something different.

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error, or it gives wrong plot or it doesn't display anything?

Comment: I use jupyter to run it.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to assign only one y value to x. When I run it I get a graph with all the years in x and their respective y values. The Dropdown-Menu is not properly linked to those x and y values. My goal is to tap the Dropdown-Menu and select one year then the graph pops up and shows me the selected year and the respective y value.

Comment: you expect too much - dropdown executes `Dropdown_Menu` with selected value but it will not select values from list `x,y` - YOU have to filter data to display plot with only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropdown` executes `Dropdown_Menu` with selected `value` but it will not select values from list `x,y`. You have to do it.

For some reasons `dropdown.observe()` doesn't works for me so I used `widgets.interact()`

**EDIT:** it seems `dropdown.observe()` works only in `juputer notebook` but not in `jupyter lab` (which I use) and it would need widget `Output()` to work. If you will use `dropdown.observe()` then in `Dropdown_Menu` you have to use `value = value.new`.

```
%matplotlib inline

import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
        #options=['2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019'],
        #value='2009',
        options=list(range(2009, 2020)), # integers instead of strings
        value=2009,  # integer instead of string
        description='Jahr:',
)

def Dropdown_Menu(value=2009):

    #print(type(value))
    #value = int(value)  # I dont have to convert if `Dropdown` uses integer values

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.dpi = 150

    x = [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
    y = [130, 137, 104, 147, 401, 274, 234, 770, 857, 746, 704]

    # get all value for `year >= value`
    #pairs = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(x, y) if a >= value] # use `==` to get only one value
    #selected_x, selected_y = zip(*pairs)

    # select values
    pos = x.index(value)
    selected_x = x[pos]
    selected_y = y[pos]

    print('x:', selected_x)
    print('y:', selected_y)

    ax.plot(selected_x, selected_y, label="Flugstunden pro Jahr", marker=".")

    ax.legend()

    ax.set_title("Flugstunden")
    ax.set_xlabel("Jahr")
    ax.set_ylabel("Flugstunden")
    ax.set_facecolor((0.9,0.9,0.9))

    #plt.show()

widgets.interact(Dropdown_Menu, value=dropdown)
#dropdown.observe(Dropdown_Menu, names="value")    
#display(dropdown)
```

---

**EDIT:** similar code with [ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl) which gives `interactive plot` - so it doesn't have to replot all again and again but it can replace only line(s) (remove old line and plot new line) or it can replace only data used in line (without removig line)

```
%matplotlib widget 
# needs ipympl

import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
        #options=['2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019'],
        #value='2009',
        options=list(range(2009, 2020)), # integers instead of strings
        value=2009,  # integer instead of string
        description='Jahr:',
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.dpi = 150

x = [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
y = [130, 137, 104, 147, 401, 274, 234, 770, 857, 746, 704]

line, = ax.plot(x, y, label="Flugstunden pro Jahr", marker=".")

ax.legend()

ax.set_title("Flugstunden")
ax.set_xlabel("Jahr")
ax.set_ylabel("Flugstunden")
ax.set_facecolor((0.9,0.9,0.9))

#plt.show()

def on_change1(value=2009):
    """remove old line(s) and plot new line(s)"""

    #print(type(value))
    #value = int(value)   # I don't have to convert string to integer

    # get all value for `year >= value`
    #pairs = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(x, y) if a >= value] # use `==` to get only one value
    #selected_x, selected_y = zip(*pairs)

    # select data 
    pos = x.index(value)
    selected_x = x[pos]  # create `selected_x` to keep original values in `x`
    selected_y = y[pos]  # create `selected_y` to keep original values in `y`

    print('x:', selected_x)
    print('y:', selected_y)

    # remove old line(s)
    for l in ax.lines:
        l.remove()

    # plot new line(s)
    ax.plot(selected_x, selected_y, label="Flugstunden pro Jahr", marker=".")   


def on_change2(value=2009):
    """keep line, remove all data from line and use new data with the same line"""

    #print(type(value))
    #value = int(value)   # I don't have to convert string to integer

    # get all value for `year >= value`
    #pairs = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(x, y) if a >= value] # use `==` to get only one value
    #selected_x, selected_y = zip(*pairs)

    # select data 
    pos = x.index(value)
    selected_x = x[pos]  # create `selected_x` to keep original values in `x`
    selected_y = y[pos]  # create `selected_y` to keep original values in `y`

    print('x:', selected_x)
    print('y:', selected_y)

    line.set_xdata(selected_x)
    line.set_ydata(selected_y)
    #fig.canvas.draw()

widgets.interact(on_change1, value=dropdown) 
#widgets.interact(on_change2, value=dropdown)
```